# solve the Partial Differential Equation for $U(t,x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

solve the Partial Differential Equation for $U(t,x)$. $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = x$$

Solution: $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} -x = 0$$ $$\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} -x = \int 0$$. now i have $$t-xt + c=0$$. Does that mean the solution for $U(t,x) = t-xt +c$.

I have a feeling i am doing this right whatsoever, he has been a long time since i have done ODE.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Here is how to solve it.

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=x$

Integrate both sides with respect to $t$ and we get

$u(t,x)=tx+c(x)$ where $c(x)$ is any function of $x$.

Comment: i have a feeling that was not right. thanks..

Comment: Why is that? Explain where you are finding trouble.

Comment: Also, to check a solution, differentiate both sides and see if it works or not.

Comment: No i mean your solution is correct. sorry for the misunderstaning

Comment: Oh, alright. You should use the past tense and say "I had a feeling". In any case, accept the answer if you find it sufficient.

Comment: how would you have solved it if the equation was a second order. would you have differentiate both sides twice i am assuming

Comment: I did not differentiate here. You differentiate to check if you did things right. Post another question if you need another differential equation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29268/discussion-between-user146269-and-hasan-saad).